# Spark Scala- how to reject bad records (malformed) from Datarame and save these rejected records in a new file

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, vertica

I am creating a simple spark streaming job that reads data from Kafka and loads into a Database table. But sometimes due to malformed records or datatype mismatch job fails. Debugging and point out problematic offsets in such scenarios is very difficult. Is there a way while loading the DF to table I can redirect erroneous rows to a separate file for further analysis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend NOT to do file writes as it will cause significant performance drops on your application. Instaed create a separate Kafka topic for records with errors and read from there for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input Vikas, I'll definitely try to reroute the erroneous rows to separate Kafka topic. But My problem here is I am not able to identify the erroneous rows, As loading into database is not row by row operation (using copy commands instead). So if a DF is having 1000 rows and bad rows are only few, I am getting all the 1000 rows in catch block, Is there a way I can get only the corrupted rows.

Comment: I am using Vertica as a DataBase and it has a spark connector to write into DB, which Internally creates ORC files in HDFS and then fires copy commands over it.

Comment: @mt_leo, i haven't worked with the Vertica connector, so cant help much with it. Try to read on the documentation and see if you can use filters to drop the unwanted records.